# Get Distinct List of string from List of List string using Linq

Tags: linq, predicate

My List collection like below

```
List<Class> classes = new List<Class>()
{
    new Class() 
    { 
        className = "A",
        students = new List<Student>()
        { 
            new Student{ name="SA"}, 
            new Student{ name="SB"},
            new Student{ name="SC"},
        }
    },
    new Class()
    {
        className = "B",
        students = new List<Student>()
        { 
            new Student{ name="SD"}, 
            new Student{ name="SA"},
            new Student{ name="SA"},
        }                   
    }
}
```

I want the Distinct student name from the **classes** Using **Linq** in the format `List<string>`. I tried to get in single linq query but get like., `List<List<string>>`. I need `List<string>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
var students = classes.SelectMany(p => p.Students).Select(p => p.Name).Distinct();
```

The [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) merges the `List<Student>`, the second `Select` selects only the Name of the student.